# Default path of program installed per user on Windows

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I'm creating WiX installer for my WPF application on Windows. My goal is to allow users without admin rights to install this program, but in the installer, the default path is currently set to Program Files which causes an Access Denied error.

What is the best practice, what should be the default installation path in per-user installation?. Is `%LOCALAPPDATA%` OK?

Answer (score 0):

All your `Component` or `ComponentGroup` belongs to a Directory

Dictionary.wxs

```xml
      <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="LocalAppDataManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="LocalAppDataProductDatabaseFolder" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="AppDataManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="AppDataProductDatabaseFolder" Name="$(var.ProductName)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
```

Product.wxs

```xml
<?include .\Dictionary.wxi ?>
...
<ComponentGroup Id="MyCoreComponent" Directory="AppDataProductDatabaseFolder">
...
```

`Manufacturer` and `Productname` are just variables you can use your hard coded strings as well

Comment: when you are using the `WIX_UI` **UiRef** maybe have a look to `<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="AppDataProductDatabaseFolder" />`